# Parallel.ForEach AgregateException - A veces tengo problemas utilizando el foreach en paralelo

Tags: c#, multitasking

A veces tengo problemas usando el `foreach` en paralelo (tengo un `for` dentro del `foreach` que agrega valores a una lista), cuando el numero de iteraciones por hilo es numerosa obtengo esa excepcion. A veces es mas lento que el `foreach` normal, no se como evaluar la situacion indicada para usar paralelo, si alguien pudiera orientarme seria genial.
Esto es lo que tengo adentro de la funcion

```
Parallel.For(MemoryRegion, r => {

            if (pattern.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < region.Length; i++)
                    if (region[i] == pattern[0])
                        for (int x = 1; x < pattern.Length; x++)
                            if (region.Length <= i + pattern.Length) break;
                            else if (pattern[x] != region[i + x])
                            {
                                if (region[i + x] == pattern[0])break;
                                else if (x == pattern.Length - 1)
                                { i += x; break; }
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (x == pattern.Length - 1)
                                addresses.Add(new IntPtr((int)r.BaseAddress + i));
            }
            else for (int i = 0; i < region.Length; i++)
                    if (region[i] == pattern[0])
                        addresses.Add(new IntPtr((int)r.BaseAddress + i));
```

Comment: Publica el fragmento de código que sea relevante, te invito a leer [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No es como si nunca he hecho una pregunta, igual gracias por tu enorme ayuda.

Comment: Hola @Mr.Noone, una **AggreagteException** es lo que una ejecución asyncrona lanza cuando una o mas excepciones se producen en algun hilo de ejecución de la tarea, podrías decirnos que excepcion(es) se encuentran dentro de la AggregateException? Revisa la propiedad **InnerExceptions**

Comment: Al ser una ejecución en paralelo, la colección que estés usando debe ser thread-safe, para esto ya hay alguna implementadas en el namespace System.Collections.Concurrent

Comment: La libreria Parallel  determina de forma automatica cuantos hilos ejecutar dependiendo de la coleccion y procesadores disponibles. Para el tema de manejo de excepciones este link te podria servir https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1